# Facebook Likes for multiple pages in a domain

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

The problem to solve:

1. Imagine I have a domain and corresponding web site at `http://my-awesome-site`
2. On this site I have 10,000 pages.
3. Each page has a Facebook Like button.
4. How do I retrieve the number of likes per page from the Facebook Graph?

It's possible to look up the total number of likes per URL using a simple GET request (examples: [google.com](https://graph.facebook.com/http://google.com/), [google.com/reader](https://graph.facebook.com/http://google.com/reader), [news.google.com](https://graph.facebook.com/http://news.google.com)). But is it possible to get a similar list for an entire domain, broken down by page? Something with results like:

```
{
   "id": "http://my-awesome-site/",
   "shares": 12345
},
{
   "id": "http://my-awesome-site/page1.html",
   "shares": 5678
},

....

{
   "id": "http://my-awesome-site/page10000.html",
   "shares": 9012
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this also via facebook graph
seperate ids with commas

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://techcrunch.com,http://mashable.com
```

the result will be a json, shown below

```
{
   "http://mashable.com": {
  "id": "http://mashable.com",
  "shares": 14436 
},
"http://techcrunch.com": {
   "id": "http://techcrunch.com",
  "shares": 2144
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best you can do is (using the [link_stat table](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/)):

```
SELECT url, share_count
FROM link_stat
WHERE url IN ("http://my-awesome-site/", "http://my-awesome-site/page1.html"...)
```

But if you have 10,000 pages you'll have to break it into multiple requests.
You can however use the [Batch Requests](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/batch/) api to then combine some requests.

That solution should lower the amount of http requests considerably if that is what you're after.